# java loop till object list is empty

Tags: java, jquery, sorting

This code is trying to sort the grades from highest to lowest.

My code:

```
public static Grades sort(Grades mergedGrades, Grades repeat) {
Grades sortedGrades = new Grades();
Grade highComp = null;
Grade highest = mergedGrades.get(0);
int index = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < mergedGrades.size(); j++) {
     highComp = mergedGrades.get(j);
     if (highComp.getGpa() > highest.getGpa()) {
         highest = highComp;
         //debug: System.out.println("getGpa: "+highest.getGpa());
         index = j;
     }
}
sortedGrades.add(highest);
mergedGrades.remove(index);
```

Every time found a highest it would add to sortedGrades object, and remove the 
grades with index. However, I don't know how to make it loop till it's empty. Please lecture me. thanks.

professor's class:

```
public int size() {
    return this.size;
}

public boolean contains(Grade grade) {

    for(int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
        if(this.gradeArray[i].equals(grade)) {
            return true ;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `while (!sortedGrades.isEmpty()) { ... }`

Comment: unfortunately, this class didn't include .isEmpty().

Comment: This seems like an inefficient sorting algorithm. If you can put them all into a list, you can sort that directly instead.

Comment: Yes, this is a basic java course. My professor wants us to have better foundation. That's why he wants us to do it this way.

Comment: *unfortunately, this class didn't include .isEmpty()* Did you write the class? Or do you have access to the class's code?

Comment: professor provides the class, and we tend to not fix it.

Comment: Does it have a `size` or equivalent method to determine the number of elements? Then use it instead

Comment: it does have size.

Comment: `while (!sortedGrades.size() > 0) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, MadProgrammer. it appears error that "operator '!' cannot be applied to 'int'." I tried to change to == or != to 0. There is no error, but it didn't get in the loop either.

Comment: Actually, MadProgrammer, you help me solve the issue. it works after I set the parameter MergedGrades != 0. Thank you.

Comment: You're correct!!! it also works. Thanks, Josh.

Comment: Joint effort, good hustle!

Comment: Did you try out the for loops? I'd be interested to know whether they compile, particularly the improved for loop.

Comment: Please remember to up-vote and choose an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this class:

```
public int size() {
    return this.size;
}

public boolean contains(Grade grade) {
    for(int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
        if(this.gradeArray[i].equals(grade)) {
            return true ;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use `size()` method to get the size.

You can place your logic inside a while loop that should loop till `mergedGrades.size() > 0`.

```
public static Grades sort(Grades mergedGrades, Grades repeat) {
    Grades sortedGrades = new Grades();
    Grade highComp = null;
    Grade highest = mergedGrades.get(0);
    int index = 0;

    while (mergedGrades.size() > 0) {        
        for (int j = 0; j < mergedGrades.size(); j++) {
            highComp = mergedGrades.get(j);
            if (highComp.getGpa() > highest.getGpa()) {
                highest = highComp;
                //debug: System.out.println("getGpa: "+highest.getGpa());
                index = j;
            }
         }
         sortedGrades.add(highest);
         mergedGrades.remove(index);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a while loop you could use:

```
while(mergedGrades.size() > 0)
```

Or you could use a nested for loop:

```
int initialMergedGradesLength = mergedGrades.size()
for(int i = 0; i < initialMergedGradesLength; i++)
```

Or this improved for loop:

```
for(Grade mergedGrade : mergedGrades)
```

although I'm not sure whether that last one would compile.